# Simple way to copy node from existing XML-File to New XML-File

Tags: powershell

I have an existing (source-)XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Base>
  <Meta>
    <Element>Value</Element>
  </Meta>
  <Settings>
    <Hostname>Computer01</Hostname>
  </Settings>
  <Data>
    <Element>Value</Element>
  </Data>
</Base>
```

I import this XML-file to the Variable "`$Xml`" with the following PowerShell-Code:

```
$Xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument ; $Xml.Load( $PathToXml )
```

I want to export/save the `<Settings>` node (+children) from `$Xml` to a new XML-File, that does not exist yet.

As for this example the new destination-XML file should look somehow like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Base>
  <Settings>
    <Hostname>Computer01</Hostname>
  </Settings>
</Base>
```

My temporary solution is to copy over the whole source-xml and select and remove the unwanted nodes, but this is not a clean solution. I also tried to build up a new XML from scratch, but that used a lot of code and I am sure, there is a cleaner and simpler way to get this task done.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will accomplish what you need if you are okay with using XPath syntax.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content source.xml)
$Nodes = $xml.SelectNodes('Base/*[name() != "Settings"]')
foreach ($Node in $Nodes) {
    [void]$xml.Base.RemoveChild($Node)
}
$xml.Save("c:\temp\destination.xml")
```

An alternative, relying on the `where()` method to find the node names to remove, is the following.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content source.xml)
$NodesToRemove = $xml.Base.ChildNodes.Name.where{$_ -ne 'Settings'}
foreach ($NodeName in $NodesToRemove) {
    $node = $xml.Base.SelectSingleNode($NodeName)
    [void]$xml.Base.RemoveChild($node)
}
$xml.Save("c:\temp\destination.xml")
```

**Explanation:**

`$xml` stores the XML contents as an XmlDocument type by use of the `[xml]` type accelerator. `$NodesToRemove` is an array that holds the names of all child nodes of Base not named Settings. Then the nodes matching the names within the array are found and subsequently removed. `Save()` is used to store the updated XML content.

Comment: I did just implement it this way. Thank you.